# 20.04 LTS How to add a user to a group with an OEM install

Tags: system-installation, kvm-virtualization, groups, oem

I want to OEM install Ubuntu 20.04LTS and distribute it with KVM installed.
A user who boots the installed OS must be a member of the "libvirt" group in order to use KVM, but how do I set it to automatically join the group the first time it boots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe make use of **cloud-init** for [automated-install](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-quickstart).

Also the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/963232/1326509) might be helpful.

Comment: I was able to achieve the desired behavior by configuring /etc/adduser.conf.
Thank you very much.